# How to exclude some column while model binding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was working on an ASP.NET MVC project where I have to bind a view model to a view but I don't want the column `Tracking_Id` to be edited by the user, at first I avoided that by using

```
 [Bind("Id,ContratId,OrganizationName,ContratDate,StartDate,EndDate,DateUploaded,MediumName,LastEditorUserId")]
```

on my post handler action parameter but I was forced to use a view model class and I couldn't do that anymore since I can only use that attribute on a parameter. The problem is if I modify the rendered website input field `value` and "name" to `contrat.Tracking_Id` and submit the form then it updates the `Tracking_Id` column and I'm afraid that might cause a security issue. I'm still new to the framework and thanks in advance.

The `Contrat` class:

```cs
public class Contrat
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ContratId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ContratDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateUploaded { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string documentPath { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Medium")]
    public string MediumName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MediumName")]
    public virtual Medium Medium { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Edited by")]
    public string LastEditorUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LastEditorUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string TrackingID { get; set; }
}
```

The view model:

```cs
public class ContratUpsertVM
{
    [DisplayName("Contrat Document")]
    public IFormFile documentPath { get; set; }
    public Contrat contrat { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the `BindAttribute` can be used on class as well, see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.bindattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0 If you cannot design a dedicated view model class (that contains only bindable properties), then you need to use `BindAttribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom modelbinding to exclude the `TrackingID` property.

**CustomModelBinder.cs:**

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }
        var model = new Contrat();
        var properties = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Properties;
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            var valueresult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "." + property.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (valueresult != null)
            {
                
                if(property.Name != "TrackingID")
                {
                    
                    if (property.ModelType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, Convert.ToDateTime(valueresult));
                    }else if(property.ModelType == typeof(Int32))
                    {
                        model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, int.Parse(valueresult));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, valueresult);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then set it on the Contrat property.

```
public class ContratUpsertVM
{
    [DisplayName("Contrat Document")]
    public IFormFile documentPath { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))]
    public Contrat contrat { get; set; }
}
```